# Android: LocationListener and getLastKnownLocation

Tags: android, gps, location, locationlistener

I have a Service which is running every minute and is supposed to constantly track location. The Service implements LocationListener. I feel like I'm not understanding this correctly though because I'm not actually using the LocationListener methods:
onLocationChanged
onProviderEnabled
onProviderDisabled
etc

I have those methods in my Class but I don't actually do anything with them. All I'm doing is every time my service runs I call LocationManager.getLastKnownLocation for both GPS and Network Provider depending on which ones are available.

This is what my code looks like:

**Service runs every minute:**

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, GPSTracker.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, i, 0);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    if(isOn) {
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), POLL_INTERVAL, pi);
    } else {
        alarmManager.cancel(pi);
        pi.cancel();
    }
```

**I handle the Intent:**

```
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Log.i(TAG, "In onHandleIntent!");
    Location currentLocation = getLocation(this);
    if(currentLocation == null) {
        saveLocation(-8.0, -8.0, "nothing", "nothing", "nothing");
    } else {
        Geocoder geocoder;
        List<Address> addresses;
        geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        try {
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
            String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
            String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryCode();
            String state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
            saveLocation(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude(), city, state, country);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**And getLocation() does the real work:**

```
 public Location getLocation(Context context) {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) context
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            // no network provider is enabled
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                Log.d("Network", "Network");
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
            // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location;
}
```

Something doesn't seem right though. For one, like I said I don't use any LocationListener methods, and also it doesn't seem to be very accurate. When I test on my phone sitting at my computer desk it gets it spot on every time. However, today I had this running on my phone once at work and another time when I was walking down the street and the locations it got for these places was like a mile away from both of them. Weirdly, it got the exact same wrong location for both of these places. These were both with Network providers as I didn't have my GPS on.

What am I doing wrong, and if I'm not doing anything wrong, how can I get this to be more accurate?

Comment: Where did you got this code from???
I think this code is written by me :P :P

Comment: and for your information, location from GPS varies a lot greatly. So you need to eliminate the points which are out of your way completely.

Comment: I got the code from this blog:
http://niravranpara.blogspot.se/2013/04/android-get-current-gps-location.html

Comment: And yes I know it varies greatly, but I think my main problem is that in the blog post this is not running in a background service, it's running right along side the app. I need mine to work even when the app is not present.

Comment: You can easily move the code from an Activity to a service. I dont have the exact code, but i have a code that sends user's location to the server periodically. Send me your email if you want the code.

Comment: That'd probably be very helpful! I'm kind of a noob to stackoverflow though, where do I find your email?

Comment: its on my profile here by clicking on my name after the comments. Or you can google "cooldudeatish" to get all details about me

Comment: Sent it on Facebook. I could not find any other email. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getLastKnownLocation () will provide the  last known location(not the current location).The location could be out-of-date, if the device was turned off and moved to another location.

You need to use LocationClient to get the current location using Google Location Service. It simple to integrate. You need to create a instance to LocationClient and connect. There are callback method when the connection  is established.Once connected you can retrieve the current location from mLocationClient.getLastLocation() (Returns the best most recent location currently available).

check this link https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

Comment: So we have to use the Google Play Services in order to get a current location?

Comment: Yes, since LocationClient extends GooglePlayServicesClient

Comment: But what if Google Play Services is not available?

Comment: It won't work, You need to make sure GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

Comment: I can try working with GooglePlayServices, but then what is the purpose of LocationListener and the onLocationChanged method if it doesn't do what I think it'd do?

Comment: As Location Client is the latest, it is believed that it is more efficient in getting the location.

Comment: That makes sense, but it just seems like LocationClient is most likely going to run into the same problem. The getLastLocation method returns the most recent location available. Isn't that the same thing onLocationChanged is supposed to do? When onLocationChanged is called, that is supposed to update the lastKnownLocation, right? Could my problem be that my service doesn't last long enough for the location change to be picked up? It runs every minute sure, but it probably runs for like a second tops.

Comment: I believe that, lastKnownLocation should provide accurate when onLocationChanged called. But there could be issue  , thats why google came with LocationClient. I have used LocationClient in one of my app in playstore , its providing accurate location

Comment: Ok, I'll look into it. I'm not doubting you, but by any chance does your app do all of it's location stuff in a background service?

Comment: no, it will connect to location client when the app start activity

Comment: Ok, that's my concern, I need to check current location from a background service that runs every few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

As your concern is to get more accurate result then you should use GPS. You can simply add a GPS enable button to ask the user for turning on the GPS.

```
gpsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                isGpsON = true;
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

You didn't use any LocationListener but I think you should use that to take the location update on

```
@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    getLocation(this);
}
```